# Randomize Sql query with two Tables

Tags: sql, vb.net

With this sql query i can randomize `IDcolumn1`, `Packett1`, `Packett2` and display the result in `DataGridView`. How to add in this query other column named `Packett3` from another table and randomize it all together. Table 2 contains `IDcolumn2` and `Packett3`.
My query :

```
Dim sql As String = String.Format(
    "SELECT Top {0} 
         IDcolumn1, 
         Packett1, 
         Packett2 
     FROM 
         MASTER
     ORDER BY
         NEWID()", rows)
```

Comment: your question is probably more about SQL than .net.

Comment: What do you mean from adding another column? Do you mean SQL joins?

Comment: Yes Ali ..SQL joint .. but I could not put correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be, not the most efficient but works (Tested!)

```sql
   select top(10) 
       IDcolumn1, 
       Packett1, 
       Packett2,
       IDcolumn2,
       Packett3
   From
       (select 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY newid() ASC) AS F1,  
            IDcolumn1, 
            Packett1, 
            Packett2 
        from Master) as t1 inner join
       (select  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY newid() ASC) AS F1,
            IDcolumn2,
            Packett3 
        from table2)  as t2 on t1.f1 = t2.f1
```

what you see, I use inline view with generation of fake ids which can be matched from one table to another.

Comment: Thank you T.S. please i am very beginner ..if you can name the fields in query as i named them in my first question

Comment: @GAVIOTA Ok, go ahead. You just need to replace `table2` with real table name and it should work

Comment: Dear anonymous - when you downvote, you need to leave a reason. There is no reason here as code works

Comment: Thank you very much T.S.very nice of you.your code work very well.the problem is solved I just have one last remark..sometimes when I randomize I will have empty cells in  DatagridView1 .. how to prevent displaying an empty cell please

Comment: @GAVIOTA which fields are empty? You need to identify which data is nullable and filter to get rid of this.  In inline view [For example] add `. . . from table2 where Packett2 is not null) as . . . `

Comment: Somethime empty cell in column1 .. somethime empty cell in column2 ..randomly empty cell

Comment: Just to learn the method.if i want to put a database access
how to change (order by NEWID) please

Comment: *"Somethime empty cell in column1 .. somethime empty cell in column2"* - your empty sells come from DB. You need to trim them using `WHERE... is not NULL`. In sql server it is also possible empty string `''`, so you do `WHERE field is not NULL and field <> ''`. *"if i want to put a database access"* - not sure what you mean

Comment: I am a beginner and i just want to learn lesson.i have tried your code with a sql server database it works fine and very well.i have changed this code with a database access with the same names of the columns and tables but it did not work.

Comment: @GAVIOTA you probably mean "Access Database" and not "database access"? These are 2 different things. Call it "MS Access" for clarity. Yea, well. these are 2 different SQL engines. And if you want answer for MS Access sql, ask another question specific to that database. I have not worked with access for 15 years now